# can't access wordpress normally anymore; after login weird page opens

Tags: php, wordpress

I have no idea what's wrong, but I just tried to log into wordpress on my server, but right after I login I get the following page:

Index of /cc-common/wp-admin

Parent Directory

admin-ajax.php

admin-footer.php

admin-functions.php

admin-header.php

admin-post.php

admin.php

async-upload.php

categories.php

comment.php

ETC ETC

it sort of lists  all files...

What did I screw up?? any clue?

Comment: Do you have an index page in this directory?

Comment: `.php` needs to be parsed as PHP, and the `DirectoryIndex` needs to use `index.php` as a possibility, and there has to actually be `index.php` in the wp-admin directory.

Comment: try reinstalling it, you might have accidentally misplaced a .htaccess file that controls which index page to show

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wet the `DirectoryIndex` in apache (or .htaccess). It sounds like you are just getting a directory listing (which is default if there is no default file specified).

Comment: But doesn't worpress do that automatically??
In my root I have .htaccess with DirectoryIndex for the main.html file as the home page.
To what do I have to set the DirectoryIndex then?

Comment: Well, is "main.html" in the list of files that it displays? If not, then you need to set it to a file that exists there (probably index.php)

Comment: ooew.. I got it, 
DirecotyIndex index.php and it was fixed!! thanks for the clue. It was probably screwed up because I used a DirectoryIndex in the root or something..

Comment: remember that the .htaccess directive will cascade to directories below it.

Comment: @webdestroya. yes main.html exists only in the root, and that is where my .htaccess is located.
But wordpress is installed in a subfoled called cc-common and there there's an .htaccess file as well, but that one is the standard one created by Wordpress. So I think when I added the DirectoryIndex to the .htaccess in the root, it messed it up for all other folders as well..

Comment: Yes, because as @Steve said, they will cascade down.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make the DirectoryIndex in the .htaccess that is located in the root only make work for the root??

Comment: Wrap it in `<Directory /the/root> DirectoryIndex main.html </Directory>`

Comment: doesn't work, do I have put the full path instead /the/root ?? like <Directory /home/www/mydomain.com> DirectoryIndex main.html </Directory> 
because this doesn't work

Comment: Yes, `/the/root` was just a placeholder/example